# Spring boot Not a managed type: class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, spring-mvc

Estoy aprendiendo spring-boot usando intelliJ como y estoy haciendo un pequeño programa que me muestre todos los clientes de mi base de datos en una tabla en HTML pero al momento de iniciar el programa la shell me muestra los siguientes errores:

Este mismo error se muestra para cada clase creada.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clienteRepository' defined in com.MywebApp.webApp.ClienteRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on WebAppApplication: Not a managed type: class com.MywebApp.webApp.Cliente
```

Estas son las classes que tengo creadas:

**Main:**

```
package com.MywebApp.webApp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.MywebApp.webApp")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.MywebApp.webApp")
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Cliente:**

```
package com.MywebApp.webApp;

import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name = "cliente")

public class Cliente {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @Column(name = "apellido")
    private String apellido;
    @Column(name = "edad")
    private int edad;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public Cliente() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

**Controlador:**

```
package com.MywebApp.webApp;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class Controlador {
    private final ClienteServicio clienteServicio;

    public Controlador(ClienteServicio clienteServicio) {
        this.clienteServicio = clienteServicio;
    }

    @GetMapping("/clientes")
    public List<Cliente> getAllClients() {
        return clienteServicio.getAllClients();
    }
}
```

**ClienteSevicio:**

```
package com.MywebApp.webApp;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
@Service
public class ClienteServicio {
    private final ClienteRepository clienteRepository;

    public ClienteServicio(ClienteRepository clienteRepository) {
        this.clienteRepository = clienteRepository;
    }

    public List<Cliente> getAllClients() {
        return clienteRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

**ClienteRepository:**

```
package com.MywebApp.webApp;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ClienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Cliente, Long>{
}
```

Intente usar la anotacion EntityScan y algunas otras soluciones que vi en internet pero no he tenido exito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que se ve en el código te falta importar la clase `Cliente` en `ClienteRepository`.

```
import com.MywebApp.webApp.Cliente;
```

Esto causa que no se pueda crear un bean de `ClienteRepository` pues no encuentra la definición de `Cliente`, lo cual a su vez impide que se cree un bean de `ClienteServicio`.

Sucede lo mismo en `ClienteServicio` (falta importar el `ClienteRepository`) y también en `ClienteController` (falta importar `ClienteServicio`).